# Copy data from a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data from a column in a dynamic (ever changing) spreadsheet, into another spreadsheet. The original also has data that I don't need so, I need this removed. The copy and paste part is easy, but, when I record it and then run it, I get an error.

```
Sub BOS()

Sheets("BOX").Select
Range("N17").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$S$61").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("NA", "These will be listed in the FDO Report- see notes.", "will be included in the FDO Report"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Rows("6:52").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$S$56").AutoFilter Field:=1
Range("L25").Select
End Sub
```

error screenshot: [image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. Firstly, both images in your description show the code so we don't actually know what the error is. If you can put your code in description, it will be easier for people to copy it rather than re-type it (if you don't know how to format it in description, I'm sure someone will do it for you). Be prepared for an answer that will probably be a lot more efficient than the recorded code but if you are just starting VBA, it will probably take some investigation on your part to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it's erroring because it's not finding any blank cells. The easiest solution without greatly changing the code around too much would be to replace these lines:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

With this:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection) > 0 Then
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub BOS()
    With Sheets("BOX")
        .Range(.Range("N17"), .Range("N17").End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    On Error Resume Next
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Range("$A$3:$S$61").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("NA", "These will be listed in the FDO Report- see notes.", "will be included in the FDO Report"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("6:52").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("$A$3:$S$56").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your suggestions figured it out in the end.